# Prepend two lines containing comments and URLs before specific line in python-scripts using sed

Tags: sed, find, regular-expression, python, block-comment

In some of my `python`-scripts, I've put the line `if __name__ == '__main__'` in order to make the content only be executed, when the script is run itself as `main`-script (as opposed to being imported, see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/12298276)).

As I've found that out just recently, I wanted to add two informative comment-lines before that line using `sed`.

*The lines I want to prepend are:*

```
# Docs on scope of __name__ == "__main__": https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/12298276
# -> Makes boolean "execute_in_script = True/False" obsolete
```

In order to accomplish this, I put up the following `find` - `sed` - command which shall make the desired change in all my `python`-scripts automatically:

```
find /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -not -path "*.history*" -not -path '*__pycache__*' -type f -exec sed -i -Ee '/^if __name__ == '__main__':.*/i # Docs on scope of __name__ == "__main__": https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/12298276\n# -> Makes boolean "execute_in_script = True/False" obsolete' {} \;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It seems to be running as it takes like 30 seconds to complete, but there is neither any output in the console, nor changes in the `python`-scripts.

How do I have to correct my `sed`-string, which is like `/line of interest/i Lines to\nprepend before that line`, to make it work?

---

Documentation on how to prepend or append lines with *sed*:

See [this blog post](https://fabianlee.org/2018/10/28/linux-using-sed-to-insert-lines-before-or-after-a-match/).

Comment: Are you actually trying to match `'__main__'` or `'__main__':`? either way, single quotes don't nest, you'd need something like `'/^if __name__ == '\''__main__'\''/i` (there's no point matching a trailing `.*`)

Comment: I tried to match `'__main__':` including the colon. Thanks to your hint I've got it working now. It's also useful to know that there's not reason for matching the rest of the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @steeldriver I got it working with the following command:

```
andylu@andylu-Lubuntu-PC:~/$ find /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -not -path "*.history*" -not -path '*__pycache__*' -type f -exec sed -i -Ee '/^if __name__ == '\''__main__'\''/i # Docs on scope of __name__ == "__main__": https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/12298276\n# -> Makes boolean "execute_in_script = True/False" obsolete' {} \;
```

It was essential to replace the single-quotes `'` inside the single-quoted regex-string with `'\''` as

> single quotes don't nest.